how to use characters like ℝ in lyx listings package (in 2024)
I know there have been historic challenges with unicode characters in program listings (listings package).
Many of questions on this site are from about 10 years ago.
My question is - is it now possible in 2024 to simply include characters like ℝ in program listings in lyx?
I have tried and I get an error, and the character is omitted in the output pdf.
I am aware of the 'escape to latex' option, but it will be a huge manual effort to change all code to escaped latex.
